# How to create this doted material in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I want to created this doted material in cycles.

[image]

Uptill know i tried this.

[image]

But did not get the similar result. Any suggestion or help to get the similar effect. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the *Musgrave* texture is pretty close to what you want:

[image]